# ListFragment inside ViewPager onItemSelected not firing

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listFragment` inside a `ViewPager`. The problem is that the list `OnItemSelected` event is not fired. I can hear the feedback sound of the item being clicked but the event is not executed. I already tried setting `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` but it doesn't help.

Before I used to have a RecyclerView logic (done using Android Studio template) and it was working, but I wanted to change because it looked confusing.

I have this inside `activity_main.xml`

```
<it.grsrl.rdd.redeye.Tools.CustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

This is `fragment_list.xml`

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_asset_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And this is briefly `item_list.xml`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView />
        <TextView/>
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I did a test:
in my custom adapter I registered an OnClickListener inside the getView method and the view is receiving the click. So, who is eating my click event?

Any help?

Comment: Few things, did you try to override the ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) ? and also try to make the item_list.xml further views focusable="false" and clickable="false" and focusableInTouchMode="false". Where did you use this android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" ?, it should go for the framelayout in item_list.xml

Comment: I've set everything as you said but it doesn't change anything. I don't know how to override onInterceptTouchEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing that ListFragment already provides an overridable `onListItemClick` method. I was setting the listener in `onViewCreated()` this way:

```
getListView().setOnItemSelectedListener()
```

But eventually this is going to fail silently.

So, I just needed to override `onListItemClick` in my `ListFragment`

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            Item itm = mListener.onAssetClick(l.getItemAtPosition)
        }
    }
```